# NameError: name 'app' is not defined with Flask

Tags: python, flask, subdomain, dispatcher

I have the following *structure* in my project

```
\ myapp
    \ app
       __init__.py
       views.py
    run.py
```

And the following code:

**run.py**

```
from app import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

**_*init*_.py**

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from app import views
    return app
```

I'm trying to use the `factory design pattern` to create my `app` objects with different `config` files each time, and with a subdomain dispatcher be able to create and route different objects depending on the `subdomain` on the user request.

I'm following the Flask documentation where they talk about, all of this:

- [Application Context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/)
- [Applitation Factories](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/)
- [Application with Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#blueprints)
- [Application Dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/)

But I couldn't make it work, it seems that with my actual project `structure` there are no way to pass throw the `app` object to my `views.py` and it throw and `NameError`

> NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Comment: Sorry I just rewrite all the question again, to make it simple to read and more focus on the error.

Comment: What you are seeing is expected, the application is not created  in the global scope, so you can do `app.route`. When you use app factories you put your view functions in a blueprint to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks Miguel! Your advice works for me ;) I'll definitely buy your book men! Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After do what Miguel suggest (use the `Blueprint`)  everything works, that's the final code, working:

**_*init.py*_**

```
...

def create_app(cfg=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from api.views import api
    app.register_blueprint(api)
    return app
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import current_app, Blueprint, jsonify
api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route("/")
def index():
     # We can use "current_app" to have access to our "app" object
     return "Hello World!"
```